# Clarifying output of the pppdist function in spatstat

Tags: spatial, spatstat, r-ppp

I was hoping for a way to compare similarity between point patterns and came across the Wasserstein distance metric. In searching for a way to calculate this and explore futher with my data, I came across the pppdist function in spatstat. From a [read of the function description](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.9-5/topics/pppdist), it looks like it can compute an approximation of a range of different distance metrics including the Prohorov distance [maximum distance between matched points], minimum averaged distance between points, and the wasserstein distance which is a measure of the work needed to transform one point pattern into another.

It seems per the documentation, the way to alter the approximated distance output is by changing the q parameter - the inverse of the power applied to the sum of distances between matched points. If q is less than 1, the output is some order of the wasserstein distance. Am I understanding that correctly? So q = 0.1 would return the 1st order Wasserstein distance; q = 0.2 would return the 2nd order and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second order Wasserstein distance would be obtained by setting `q=2`, third order is `q=3` and so on. For example order `q=2` means that you are calculating the sum of squared distances and then taking the square root afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Ege, I really appreciate that! I am very new to this form of analysis.

Comment: There was one other related question about pppdist I hoped to ask - there is a parameter called cutoff which specifies the maximum euclidean distance between matched points used for the point pattern distance calculation. Is there some way to optimize this? Is it based on the expected interaction distance between points within the point patterns?

Comment: I don't know of a way to choose `cutoff`. It is a user supplied value to say that distances between points should be thresholded at this value. For example, if two points are distance 2 from each other and you set `cutoff=1`, they will appear as being distance 1 from each other and be matched based on that distance rather than the true distance of 2.